# show that sequence of functions $f_n(x) = (nx^2+1)/(nx+1)$ converges uniformly on $[1,2]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation, uniform-convergence

I have found out that this sequence of functions approaches to $1$ at $x=1$, approaches to $2$ at $x=2$, approaches to $x$ when $1<x<2$.
Now to prove the sequence converges uniformly in $[1,2]$, what should be N ?? And what is the trick to find N ?

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in[1,2]$, then\begin{align}|f_n(x)-x|&=\left|\frac{nx^2+1}{nx+1}-x\right|\\&=\left|\frac{1-x}{nx+1}\right|\\&\leqslant\frac1n.\end{align}Can you take it from here?

Comment: +1. I just changed $f(x)$ to $f_n(x)$ in the title as well as in your answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you.

Comment: @jose carlos yeah now I have proved it by choosing N>1/ epsilon but I didn't get that how you replaced second term |1-x/nx+1| with 1/n ??

Comment: Since $x\in[1,2]$, $1-x\in[-1,0]$, and therefore $|1-x|\leqslant1$. On the other hand$$|nx+1|=nx+1\geqslant nx\geqslant n,$$and therefore$$\left|\frac{1-x}{nx+1}\right|\leqslant\frac1n.$$